# How to draw Gradients in quick mask mode in new app (May 2023)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, mask

In the new photoshop (May 2023) desktop app, in quick mask mode, drawing a gradient just ads a new gradient in the layers panel. How do I get a gradient on the quick mask channel?

Comment: Sorry, desktop app - have edited question.

Comment: Usually you can simply go into quick mask mode Q and click and drag the gradient tool. The gradient will look reddish.  Note that Q toggles between quick mask mode and a selection, so if it doesn't work the first time, you may have hit Q too many times, hit it once more, and it should work.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it should do - but it doesn't - hence my question here for a solution / workaround.

Comment: Sounds like it could possibly be a bug to me. You should perhaps contact Adobe, or check their help site to see if someone has also reported it.  I'm still on a slightly older version of CC 2021 and it seems to work OK. I rarely update to the latest version as it can often take a while for them to fix the bugs.